# Skopt.gp_minimize: Passing args to objectiv function

Tags: python, optimization, parameter-passing, skopt

I am trying to implement an optimisation using gp_minimize from skopt.
However my objective functions needs some objects to work on, similar to this:

```
def objective(optimisation_parameters, trees):
    trees.manipulate(optimisation_parameters)
    trees.shake()
    return trees.count_fallen_fruits()
```

```
def optimise():
    trees = [tree.Tree() for _ in range(0,5)]
    res = gp_minimize(objectiv,space,...,args = trees)
```

Is there any (proper) way to do this? I have several ideas:

1. Read and store the trees in a pickle file each optimisation
2. Define the trees so that they are in scope for the objective function

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your idea 2 is the common option. It is utilized in [this example](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/auto_examples/hyperparameter-optimization.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-hyperparameter-optimization-py).

A scratch based on your code snippets might look like this:

```
trees = [tree.Tree() for _ in range(0,5)]

def objective(optimisation_parameters):
    trees.manipulate(optimisation_parameters)
    trees.shake()
    return trees.count_fallen_fruits()

res = gp_minimize(objective, space, ...)
```